# Materializecss Select in Symfony does not work

Tags: symfony, materialize

Using materialize in symfony:
in my project materialize select only works if I include it like this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/…/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js with jquery as well https://ajax.googleapis.com /ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js. 
But if I include jquery.js and materialize.js as local file it does not work:
  and 
please any ideia to fix it?
This is my code

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

{ 
            
            
            
            
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('select').material_select();
                });
            }

[you can see the photo of my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUnDX.png)

Comment: Can you please add your code? Also import jquery first.

Comment: I have updated my post, now you can see the photo of my code

Comment: @valdanioestevaoalbeto Linking pictures of code is not recommended as those links may disappear in the future, making the question useless to future readers who may encounter the same problem you are having. You should alternatively paste the code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question directly. You can find more information on the [mcve] page.

Comment: Ok! thank you so much i'll repeat

Comment: this is the import files: <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('build/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('build/js/materialize.js')}}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('build/js/app.js')}}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('build/js/script.js')}}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('select').material_select();
                });
            </script>

Comment: and this is the materialize select <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>